How to set SWIG generated java interface as not public
I am using SWIG to generate a Java wrapper for some C code. This C code has some constants that SWIG represents with the Java interface file below. As it stands, this interface can be accessed by classes outside the abc package because it is declared as public. How can I modify the SWIG configuration to make this interface visible only to classes within the same package (i.e., change public interface TestConstants to interface TestConstants)? I've tried several approaches (e.g., using typemaps and pragmas), but none have worked.
Here is the automatically generated Java interface file:
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This file was automatically generated by SWIG (http://www.swig.org).
 * Version 3.0.12
 *
 * Do not make changes to this file unless you know what you are doing--modify
 * the SWIG interface file instead.
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

package abc;

public interface TestConstants {
  public final static int YES = TestJNI.YES_get();
  public final static int NO = TestJNI.NO_get();
  public final static int ENABLED = TestJNI.ENABLED_get();
  public final static int DISABLED = TestJNI.DISABLED_get();
}

How can I achieve this using SWIG?
